# Ruby Regex to eliminate non word characters

Tags: ruby, regex

Hello I would like to eliminate non words characters by a Regex in Ruby.

Let's say that I have:

```
pal1 = "a@b?a"
pal1 = /[a-z0-9]/.match(pal1)
```

When I put this in http://www.rubular.com/, it says that the Match result is:
aba

But whe I run the code in my ruby it is not true, it gives only "a"

How can I change my Regex to achieve aba in pal1.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You are matching a single character. To match all, try `array_of_matches = pal1.scan(/[a-z\d]/i)`

Comment: Luis, if you found either of the answers helpful, you should select the one that was most helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html) to remove these characters.

```
pal1 = 'a@b?a'
pal1.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]/i, '')
# => "aba"
```

You can also use `scan` to match these characters and *join* them together.

```
pal1 = 'a@b?a'
pal1.scan(/[a-z0-9]/i).join
# => "aba"
```

Comment: Or `pal1.split(/[^a-z0-9]+/i).join`, and could change regexes in both `gsub` and `scan` to `/[..]+/i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of:

```
pal1.gsub!( /[^a-z\d]/i, '' )     # Kill all characters that don't match
pal1 = pal1.scan(/[a-z\d]/i).join # Find all the matching characters as array
                                  # and then join them all into one string.
```